# How to pass values to Rails app templates (-m)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-generation, template-engine

I built several templates I use for generating new Rails apps. Such as `rails new app_name -m template_name.rb`.

Now, I'd like to pass some values to my templates. Is there a possibility to do that? Something like `rails new app_name -m template_name.rb value1, value2`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass [`environment variable`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) to template:

`temp.rb`:

```
gem "#{ENV['SOMETHING']}"
gem "nokogiri"
```

and make new app:

```
$bash> SOMETHING=foo rails new blog -m temp.rb
```

in dir with app `blog`:

```
$ cat Gemfile

#...... some output

gem 'foo'
gem 'nokogiri'
```

On other hand you  can create a file with env variables and use it, create file `foo` with:

```
export SOME=foo
export OTHER=bar
```

in `temp.rb`:

```
gem "#{ENV['SOME']}"
gem "#{ENV['OTHER']}"
gem "nokogiri"
```

and now generate new rails project:

```
$bash> $(cat foo) && rails new blog -m temp.rb
```

Whats going here?
First read the `foo` file and `export` env variables, then generate new project by `temp.rb`.

in `blog/Gemfile`:

```
gem 'foo'
gem 'bar'
gem 'nokogiri'
```

Comment: Not bad. I'd like to make a wizard-like menu and pass variables to the template. I could have the wizard store values in ENV but it's not optimal, I think. Do you know of any other way?